# Cannot Use Emoji within Browsers

Tags: 20.04, browser, emoji

This is probably a *really* simple fix, but I cannot for the life of me get emoji to work in any browser (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Vivaldi) on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. I can bring up the picker with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in applications such as Text Editor, but not in the applications where I *actually* use emoji. There is no option to insert them with [a right click contextual menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PALLu.png), either.

I've tried to resolve this by:

1. installing [the Emote snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/emote/ubuntu) from Tom Watsom
2. removing and re-installing the `fonts-noto-color-emoji` package
3. changing my keyboard to an English layout (it's Japanese by default)
4. giving my dog a much-needed bath

As none of this has worked, I'm clearly missing something ...

Comment: You won’t see the ‘Insert Emoji’ option in the context menus of non-GTK apps, like Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, or LibreOffice. [source](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- GNOME Epiphany (the Linux port of Safari) is currently the only web browser that supports the native emoji picker. You can install it via [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/epiphany) or [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Epiphany).

  [image: Epiphany running under OpenSUSE Budgie, demonstrating the emoji picker]
- Alternatively, there are extensions for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/awesome-emoji-picker/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emoji-keyboard-2016-by-em/ipdjnhgkpapgippgcgkfcbpdpcgifncb) and [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/emoji-keyboard-2016-by-emojionetm/) that add an emoji picker to the toolbar.

  [image: Emoji picker extension for Firefox]

Comment: It's not too often that I add extensions to browsers, but this certainly gets the job done 

Answer (score 2):

## In 2024, this [Cross-Platform Emoji Picker](https://ryancwalsh.com/emoji_picker) is available for free.

[image: screenshot of Cross-Platform Emoji Picker]

I created this app using Electron. This is not meant to be a spammy, self-promoting post. But I built this tool for myself because the other Ubuntu options weren't good. Feel free to use it if you want.

It works on Ubuntu and also on Windows and Mac, using the same keyboard shortcut.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> to open this app (or <kbd>⌃</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> on Mac), and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> to paste into the browser.

I spent countless hours trying to enable the app to insert an emoji directly into the browser without using the clipboard. But Ubuntu (at least the Wayland version) is locked down, so this is [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816509/470749). Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. But this app is the quickest alternative I know about.